# Ionic element "cameraPhoto" not working, failing to compile or call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having trouble with the cameraPhoto element.

The error is "cannot find name 'cameraPhoto'.
Did I forget to define something? Still learning and going through the documentation for Ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/2-taking-photos

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCamera } from '@ionic/react-hooks/camera';
import { useFilesystem, base64FromPath } from '@ionic/react-hooks/filesystem';
import { useStorage } from '@ionic/react-hooks/storage';
import { isPlatform } from '@ionic/react';
import { CameraResultType, CameraSource, CameraPhoto, Capacitor, FilesystemDirectory } from "@capacitor/core";

//usePhotoGallery is our custom hook 
export function usePhotoGallery() {
    const { getPhoto } = useCamera();
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<Photo[]>([]);
    const takePhoto = async () => {
      const cameraPhoto = await getPhoto({
        resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
        source: CameraSource.Camera,
        quality: 100 
        
      });
    };
    
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
    const newPhotos = [{
        filepath: fileName,
        webviewPath: cameraPhoto.webPath
        }, ...photos];
    setPhotos(newPhotos)
    
//updated this return statement to include photos
    return {
      photos,  
      takePhoto
      
    };
  }
  

export interface Photo {
  filepath: string;
  webviewPath?: string;

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are new to React too . Here the error `Cannot find name 'takePhoto'.` is happening because you are calling a function named `takePhoto` but you haven't defined/declared the function yet .

You are following the tutorial but the tutorial isn't complete yet . `takePhoto` was defined in the [second page of the tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/2-taking-photos) .

As everything is there in the tutorial so I am not sharing any code here .

Comment: Thanks for that, now its the cameraPhoto that is not being called 'cannot find the name' error. Any ideas? Very big props to you and your account.